# Translation error in "Stack Overflow em Português" community

Tags: bug, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

In communities tab has a translation error in the "Stack Overflow em Português".

The description says:

> **For** programadores profissionais e entusiastas.

When the correct thing:

> **Para** programadores profissionais e entusiastas.

[image: The error]

Comment: Doesn't [pt.so] have [its own Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there it shows correctly, the error happens in English-speakers communities. Actually there's an error there that's exactly the oppose of this one: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2695/3117 Perhaps this should be posted in Meta SE instead of here. But the OP probably wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Math, hah, I see that now. Fine, then :)

Comment: This seems to be because the "For" at the beginning is not actually part of the description text. I bet that the code to populate the list looks something like `"For " + SESite.getDescription()`.. Should be fixed IMO.

Comment: @Math - it's OK to report bugs that affect the network on a child meta - especially if the OP is only active on one or two sites.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you for providing me this information, I didn't know.

Comment: I'd say this is a regression after [the same bug I reported on meta.ja.so](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1416/2767) was fixed. As far as I remember, previously it's translated correctly even on English sites. However, after the fix on ja.so (For → 向け), this happened.

Comment: If I hover over a site-name at the bottom of a page on SO/Meta.SO a tooltip-type thing appears, not bothering with the "For". Curiously, on pt.SO there is no tooltip appearing. That seemed to shoot down my idea of suggesting "just bin the 'For' everywhere". Further curiously, SO Na Ruskom has the tooltip, in English. Same with ja. So, fix the tooltip on pt, drop the "for" from the topbar drop-down, then there's just the migration, which perhaps has a bunch of other text, and would only cause problem when migrating from one language site to another, so rare.

Comment: However, clicking on the more(n)s at bottom goes to an SE page which says... Q&A for.... all in English, no matter where entered from.

Answer (score 22):

It's clearly an artefact of incomplete/improper localisation techniques. Each site has meta data associated with it which contains a *sentence fragment* for the site's description, which is used in various places. The issue is that this fragment was designed for an English context, and the system was not properly updated after additional languages were introduced. The menu just shows a template according to this format:

```
printf(_('For %s'), site_description);
```

`site_description` is the sentence fragment in whatever language the site is about, `For %s` is being localised as `Para %s`, `%s向け` or whatever else.

Obviously this doesn't work and produces sentences which make no sense in any language. You cannot mush sentence fragments of two different languages together and expect any sensible outcome.

It needs to be changed in one of these ways:

1. don't attempt to form complete sentences, along the lines of `Audience: %s` (quick fix, somewhat inelegant but workable)
2. localise every site description into all languages to create a grammatically correct sentence for every site in every language (huge PITA, good result, possibly misleading since description language doesn't match site language)
3. localise the `For %s` snippet according to the language of the target site, e.g. *"Para programadores profissionais e entusiastas"* and *"For programming professionals and enthusiasts"* in the same list

   ```
   printf(_('For %s', site_locale), site_description)
   ```

   (probably best outcome with least amount of work)

Comment: I support the 3rd point since personally, I think it makes sense that people who want to participate on sites written in foreign language must at least understand the site description in its language.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been fixed:

[image: Portuguese SO]

If so, a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) would be appreciated.