# Translate problem for the first word

Tags: bug

The descriptions of Stack Overflow variants are all with the first word in English:

[image]

Comment: Thought I had seen this before, or something very similar: [Translation error in “Stack Overflow em Português” community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291265/translation-error-in-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-community) was posted a while back. While it only points out the Portuguese site, it's the same issue and just hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: My guess would be that the translated portion is a "site users" description, and the "For" is automatically prepended. Note that all site descriptions start with "For". This probably seemed like a good idea at the time.

Comment: It is not only StackOverflow, it is all StackExchange sites. See rus.StackExchange.com