# Able to post an answer on a question I marked as duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, user-interface

I recently flagged [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310306/translate-problem-for-the-first-word/) as a duplicate, then left the tab open and went on my merry way.  I came back a short while later to see the "This question has been edited" banner.  I clicked it, it reloaded to show it had been marked as a duplicate.

To my surprise, I saw the answer box was still present, so I went ahead and tested it - I could still post an answer.

I think the answer box should no longer be present when you reload an edited question via the banner and the reload shows it to now be closed, as it would be if you performed a full page refresh.

---

I'm also aware of a post somewhere on the network (typically can't find it now) where it describes why and how questions that are closed can still receive answers - there's a certain grace period etc - but I believe that since I didn't even *start typing* my answer until I'd reloaded the question that this also shouldn't apply, and I would have thought it was well after (certainly > 10 mins) such a period should apply for anyway.